# omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I ma trying to use `omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter` for `h:selectOneMenu` , i am trying the example in the website of omnifaces [here](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter) but it's not working , no object is selected , i am using

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Faces Library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Primefaces Version 5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

this is my page the rest of code is [here](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter)

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
template="/templates/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="metadata">
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">


    <h:form>
        <p>
            <b>Last selected item:</b>
            <h:outputText id="selected_item"
                value="#{selectItemsBean.selectedEntity.value}" />
        </p>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="iterator" value="Items with iterator: " />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="iterator"
                value="#{selectItemsBean.selectedEntity}"
                converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose item" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemsBean.exampleEntities}"
                    var="entity" itemLabel="#{entity.value}" itemValue="#{entity}" />
                <f:ajax render="selected_item" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputLabel for="iterator_def_value"
                value="Items with iterator (default value): " />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="iterator_def_value"
                value="#{selectItemsBean.selectedEntity}"
                converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose item" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemsBean.exampleEntities}"
                    var="entity" itemLabel="#{entity.value}" />
                <f:ajax render="selected_item" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputLabel for="selectitems"
                value="Items with SelectItem list: " />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="selectitems"
                value="#{selectItemsBean.selectedEntity}"
                converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose item" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemsBean.selectItems}" />
                <f:ajax render="selected_item" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputLabel for="selectitems_array"
                value="Items with SelectItem array: " />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="selectitems_array"
                value="#{selectItemsBean.selectedEntity}"
                converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose item" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemsBean.selectItemArray}" />
                <f:ajax render="selected_item" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

so i wounder if there is any suggestion ??

Comment: I don't know if it's the best idea to use PrimeFaces alongside with OmniFaces. Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: When you debug `selectedEntity` is stored?

Comment: @QueryLars Sorry, but you're wrong. PrimeFaces is a component library (e.g. tables, improved inputs, ...) while Omnifaces is an utility library designed to make your life easier with JSF. Look at http://showcase.omnifaces.org/ to get more information.

Comment: Please elaborate the problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. As first step, is the ajax request successfully fired? I.e. no errors in JS console and a XHR in network console?

Comment: I thought OmniFaces would be a component library, too. Once again I learned something new. Thanks Stackoverflow, especially @MathieuCastets :)

Comment: @QueryLars: We created and develop/improve OmniFaces while using PrimeFaces at the same time. So it's basically the best compatible component library to use OmniFaces on. But, theoretically, OmniFaces is designed to be minimally invasive and most compatibility troubles observed and reported so far are caused by the other library and not by OmniFaces itself (for which we happily provide a workaround or even report a bug to library vendor so they can fix their mistake; e.g. Weld and Spring WebFlow made some serious mistakes in `ApplicationFactory` and they fixed it happily after a report).